# Fazer scroll de acordo com ID da section

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte **li**

```
<li class="madmaxmenu">
<a href="#mad-max">Mad Max</a>
</li>
```

e o seguinte Jquery

```
$("li.madmaxmenu").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#madmax").offset().top - 120},
    'slow');
});
```

Ou seja, quando eu clico na **li** ele vai direto para a section que informei e já informa o **href** na barra de endereço.

Por exemplo: http://madmax.com.br/#mad-max

E se eu quiser que quando o usuário digite http://madmax.com.br/#beyond-the-thunderdome na barra de endereço, ele vá diretamente para esse section, sem ter que clicar no menu, tem como? 
Fazer o mesmo processo de como se ele tivesse clicado na **li** em questão.
Site http://madmax.com.br

Comment: Ele já faz isso se utilizares um `id` em vez de uma `class`. Por exemplo se tiveres um link ou uma `li` assim: `<li id="beyond-the-thunderdome">` em vez de uma class, quando o usuário acessar o site usando o link do exemplo que deste `http://madmax.com.br/#beyond-the-thunderdome`, quando carregada a página, ele vai automaticamente "saltar" para essa secção com esse `id`. Estes são chamados de "links ancora".

Comment: Mas eu teria que informar o **id** aonde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele já faz isso automaticamente se utilizares `id`'s em vez de classes para cada secção.
Estes são chamados de links ancora! Eis um exemplo abaixo:

> Mais informações sobre como funcionam os links ancora:
> w3Schools - [HTML Links - Create a Bookmark](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)
> RapidTables - [HTML anchor link](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.htm)

**CSS:**

```
.section {
    height: 75vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #d2d2d2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="float-right">
  <li class="madmaxmenu">
    <a href="#mad-max">Mad Max</a>
  </li>
  <li class="theroadwarriormenu">
    <a href="#the-road-warrior">The Road Warrior</a>
  </li>
  <li class="beyondthethunderdomemenu">
    <a href="#beyond-the-thunderdome">Beyond The Thunderdome</a>
  </li>
  <li class="furyroadmenu">
    <a href="#fury-road">Fury Road</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="section" id="mad-max"> Secção Mad Max </div>
  <div class="section" id="the-road-warrior"> Secção Road Warrior </div>
  <div class="section" id="beyond-the-thunderdome"> Secção Beyond The Thunderdome </div>
  <div class="section" id="fury-road"> Secção Mad Max </div>
</div>
```

Agora se acessares o link de navegação adicionando como extensão ao URL qualquer um dos `id`'s da secção que pretendes ir, ele vai automaticamente saltar para essa secção. (Ou clicando num dos links de navegação que já estão a apontar para as secções existentes).

## Exemplo: **`http://minhaPagina.html#the-road-warrior`**

> No comentário que adicionei anteriormente incluí a (barra) `/` no endereço de navegação, mas não é necessário e também a forma correta de se fazer é como eu acabei de mencionar acima.
>
> No [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/egzfhrfy/) isto não vai funcionar, pois ele impede a possibilidade de acessar o link utilizando o `id` na URL, mas eu testei localmente e funciona perfeitamente!
> Boa sorte e boa continuação de programação! :)

Answer (score 1):

Você só precisa colocar a ID da section, exatamente como você colocou no link, por exemplo:

```
<li class="madmaxmenu">
<a href="#theroadwarrior">Mad Max</a>
</li>


<section id="theroadwarrior"></section>
```

Esses são os chamados links âncora...
E olha só, , com jquery você pode deixar esse scroll suave.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function filterPath(string) {
    return string
    .replace(/^\//,'')
    .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
    .replace(/\/$/,'');
    }
    $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
    var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
    if ($target) {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
    $(this).click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 300);
    return false;
    });
    }
    }
    });
    });
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: Cara, por algum motivo ele não da abre na **div** correta, olha aí. https://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/0mwcc2dc/ ou no próprio site http://madmax.com.br/#beyond-the-thunderdome

Comment: Vc está usando esses ífens "beyond-the-thunderdome" no link, e na ID tudo junto... tem que ser igual #beyondthethunderdome id="beyondthethunderdome "